# Is there a Db2 scalar function to retrieve full error message information for a given SQLCODE?

Tags: java, db2, db2-luw

I'd like to know if there is any existing solution for getting detailed DB error explanations in code if I have a SQL error code. I'd like to dump this info into log so that I won't have to look up google everytime I meet one.

Target tach stack is - Java, DB2.

Thank you!

Comment: What's wrong with Googling for an error code?  Are you expecting to have many errors?

Comment: I do have many applications sharing the same underlying framework. I'd like the same error explanation to be accessible directly from the log so that both Support and DEV are guaranteed to share the same understanding of the error, and Support can even proactively address some of them if possible, instead of going to DEV every time even if it actually would only take another look up in google.

Comment: If you are catching these SQL exceptions in your Java code, then why can't you add more information to the stack trace?  The best thing here, I think, would be to handle this at the time you actually write the log.

Comment: I'd like to do both. ST would tell where the problem happened, however any DB side errors would require detail explanations on the SQL CODE. No matter how I'd love to address every exception during runtime in desired ways, it's not always, if ever, possible.

Comment: Store verbose descriptions of SQL errors in a properties file, where the key is the numerical code.

Comment: Yeah, that could be one way to do it, and I probably will end up doing it that way if there is no other existing solutions, say a lib, that I can leverage, which is the very purpose of this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `SYSPROC.SQLERRM` will return the error message for a given SQLCODE. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0022027.html

E.g. This will return the short message for SQLCODE 100 (i.e `SQL100W`)

```
VALUES (SYSPROC.SQLERRM (100))
```

like this

```
1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL0100W  No row was found for FETCH, UPDATE or DELETE; or the result of a query is an empty table.

  1 record(s) selected.
```

and this will return the full message

```
VALUES (SYSPROC.SQLERRM ('SQL100W', '', '', 'en_US', 0))
```

will return

```
1                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

SQL0100W  No row was found for FETCH, UPDATE or DELETE; or the result of
      a query is an empty table.

Explanation: 

One of the following conditions is true:

*  No row was found that meets the search conditions specified in an
   UPDATE or DELETE statement.

*  The result of a SELECT statement was an empty table.

*  A FETCH statement was executed when the cursor was positioned after
   the last row of the result table.

*  The result of the SELECT used in an INSERT statement is empty.

No data was retrieved, updated, or deleted.

User response: 

No action is required. Processing can continue.

sqlcode: +100

sqlstate: 02000



  1 record(s) selected.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I'm looking for. I don't know why this problem was voted down, but I do hope people who share the same need will be able to see your answer!